# Using sed, awk, etc. to separate after middle dot characters

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I could use your assistance for something; I promise I tried really hard to search for answers, but no luck.

I want to separate text between every occurrence of the "·" (middle dot) character
(by syllables, basically).

```
echo con·grat·u·late | sed -e 's/·.*$/·/1'
```

The code above outputs:

> con·

That is the first part of what I want, but ultimately I would like an output of:

> con·
>   grat·
>   u·
>   late

This will involve getting the characters between the 1st-2nd, and the 2nd-3rd occurrences of "·"

If anyone can guide me in the right direction, I will really appreciate it, and I will figure the rest out on my own.

**EDIT**
My apologies, I displayed my desired output incorrectly. Your solution's worked great, however.

Since it is important for me to keep everything as a single line, how would I output the text between the first dot and the second one, to output:

```
grat·
```

I am doing it in UTF-8, Jonathan

Once again, sorry for asking the wrong thing.

Comment: Is your data in ISO 8859-1, so the middle dot (`·`) is a single byte `\xB7` or is it UTF-8 and hence U+00B7 or two bytes `\xC2\xB7`?  Either can be handled; the difference might be crucial to the pattern matching (though equally, since it is a direct substitution, even a Unicode-unaware program may well handle UTF-8 correctly).

Comment: So you don't want parts of the word on a new line? you prefer to print the characters found between the first dot and second dot only?

Comment: Yes Xorg,
I would like to print the characters between the 1st and 2nd dots,  
then 2nd and 3rd,  
then 3rd and 4th, etc.

Comment: How about `echo 'con·grat·u·late'` | awk -F. '{print $1}' etc... ($1, $2 etc will contain con,grat,u,late respectively..)

Comment: It would have been better to ask another question, after several of us already answered your original question. Your change invalidated our answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking to run characters between the dots, You can try sed like this

```
echo 'con.grat.u.late'|sed 's/\.*\./&\n/g'|sed  -n 2p|tr -d '.'
```

**to print group of characters between 1st and 2nd dot**

```
echo 'con.grat.u.late'|sed 's/\.*\./&\n/g'|sed  -n 2p|tr -d '.'
```

results

```
grat
```

note: I use `2p` to print characters between 1st dot and 2nd dot

**print group of characters between  2nd dot and 3rd**

```
echo 'con.grat.u.late'|sed 's/\.*\./&\n/g'|sed  -n 3p|tr -d '.'
```

results

```
u
```

note: I use `3p` to print characters between 2nd dot and 3rd dot

You can also do the whole thing with sed but I use `tr` command so it will be easy for you to follow. The `tr` command delete the dots before printing. If you want to dots then exclude `|tr -d '.'` from your command line.

You can also print ranges of group of characters

```
echo 'con.grat.u.late'|sed 's/\.*\./&\n/g'|sed  -n 1,3p|tr -d '.'
```

results

```
con
grat
u
```

Comment: This solved my question, thanks a bunch Xorg.

Have a great holiday weekend everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In GNU sed you can do this:

```
echo con·grat·u·late | sed -e 's/·/&\n/g'
```

The `&` stands for the matched pattern, in this example the `·`. 
Unfortunately this doesn't work in BSD sed.

For a more portable solution, I recommend this AWK,
which should work in both GNU and BSD systems:

```
echo con·grat·u·late | awk '{ gsub("·", "&\n") } 1'
```

Comment: To make it work with BSD `sed` you'll probably need to do `sed -e $'s/·/&\\\n/g'`

Comment: And, if my experiments are valid, the `sed` script doesn't work with BSD `sed` because the `\n` is not translated to newline.

Comment: @jaypalsingh: my testing on Mac OS X 10.9.5 indicates that 1, 2 or 3 backslashes do not work with BSD `sed`.

Comment: there is no need to use & in one symbol pattern

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Did you add the `$`?

Comment: @jaypalsingh: no...using the Bash [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism with the dollar at the start of the string works.  And that means that writing a single backslash at the end of one line and then a newline and the slash to mark the end of the replacement string also works (verified by experiment).  I'd be curious to know if that works with GNU `sed`.  The machine I'm working on currently doesn't have that installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple [`awk`](http://man.cx/awk) to get these words separated:

```
$ echo 'con.grat.u.late' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
con
$ echo 'con.grat.u.late' | awk -F. '{print $2}'
grat
$ echo 'con.grat.u.late' | awk -F. '{print $3}'
u
$ echo 'con.grat.u.late' | awk -F. '{print $4}'
late

$ echo 'con.grat.u.late' | awk -F. '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}' 
con
grat
u
late
```

`-F.` implies use `.` as field separator

Comment: This one looks very great, and simple.
I usually stick with SED, but awk gained my interest.

Also, I used the "·" not "." character, but I tried out 

`echo 'con·grat·u·late' | awk -F· '{print $2}'`

and it works as well.

Thanks, and happy holidays!

Comment: Just FYI, for using the non ascii characters, you _may_ need to enclose them in single quotes...

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
echo con·grat·u·late | sed -e 's/·/·\n/g'
```

that replaces every `·` with a `·` followed by a newline.

Comment: you don't need -e here to perform the same

Comment: @BallPython: You're right, but the `-e` does no damage whatsoever.